# how to design class that has char* pointer as class member variable?

Tags: c++, memory-leaks

First i want to introduce my situation :

I have write some classes that has char* pointer as private class member.And also this project has GUI, so when click buttons,some functions may execute more than one time.Those classes are designed **single class** in project.But some functions of them can execute more than one time.Then I found my project has memory leak.

so i want to ask the following questions:

1. how to design the set function?
2. how to design the other functions that use the char* member variable?
3. how to design the class operator= function?

for example:

```
class A:
{
 public :
 setStr(char * s){//need new or just use =?};
 A & operator=(const A& other){//also need new?};
 manyTimesFunctions(char * other)
 {
  //need to use chars other to assignment str
  //how to carefully use new to avoid memory leak?
  //other may be another class's locality none const variable 

 } 
 private:
 char * str;
}
```

So ,the project only init class A once,but may use `setStr` and `manyTimesFunctions` many times.

---

#### May be the answer:

I think i have found what i need to take care of:[**copy that class**](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4172722/what-is-the-rule-of-three),that answers are really useful to me.

Comment: *I have write some classes that has char** *pointer as private class member.* Are you suggesting that you are not allowed to use `std::string`?

Comment: @RSahu for some reason,i have no choice.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This answer will be used to contrast what the other answer(s) given that state to use `std::string` (and those answers are correct -- use `std::string`).

Let's assume that you could only use `char *`, you can't for some reason use `std::string`, and that you are dealing with NULL terminated strings.  This is a synopsis of what your implementation would have to do (and please compare this with simply using `std::string`):

```
#include <algorithm>
#include <cstring>

class A
{
    public:
       // construct empty string
       A () : str(new char[1]()) {}

       // construct from non-empty
       A(const char *s) : str(new char[strlen(s) + 1])
       { strcpy(str, s); }

       // copy construct
       A(const A& rhs) : str(new char[strlen(rhs.str) + 1])
       { strcpy(str, rhs.str); }

       // destruct
       ~A() { delete [] str; }

       // assign
       A& operator=(const A& rhs)
       {
          A temp(rhs);
          std::swap(str, temp.str);
          return *this;
       }

       // setter
       void setStr(char * s)
       {
          A temp(s);
          *this = temp;
       }  

       // getter
       const char* getStr() { return str; }

     private:
        char * str;
};
```

[Live Example](http://ideone.com/1iL8yj)

After adding a couple more constructors and a getter function, this follows the [Rule of 3](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4172722/what-is-the-rule-of-three).

You see how much code we needed to add just to make the class safely copyable and assignable?  That's why using `std::string` is much more convenient than using `char *` when it comes to class members.  For `std::string` a single line needs to be changed, compared to adding the copy / assignment (and move, which I didn't show) functions.

The bottom line is that in C++ if you want strings, use strings (`std::string`) and try to keep away from using `char *` (unless you have a very compelling reason to be using `char *` to represent string data).

Comment: One way to simplify this is to define a `clone_ptr` smart pointer. Of course if that's the only single use of it then it just moves complexity around a little. But it can be generally useful, and then in total it reduces complexity wherever it's used. That follows the [**rule of zero**](https://rmf.io/cxx11/rule-of-zero/).

Comment: @Cheersandhth.-Alf  I'm trying to scare the OP into actually using `std::string`.

Comment: Why is it not a good idea to use chat pointer as class member variable.

Answer (score 3):

Just use `std::string`. It takes care of memory management for you. The member declaration then looks like

```
std::string str;
```

and the setter function looks like

```
void setStr( char const* s ) { str = s; }
```

Where you want to use the string and need a `char const*`, just write `str.c_str()`.

With use of standard library types like `std::string`, and no manual dynamic allocation, you generally don't need to be concerned about `operator=`: the compiler-generated copy assignment works nicely.

---

By the way, it's generally a good idea to decide on some *naming convention* for member variables. Common ones for C++ include `str_`, `mStr`, and `my_str`. The underscore suffix is perhaps the most common one, but don't use a leading underscore like `_str`, because although technically allowed it conflicts with the conventions for implementation defined names (e.g. leading underscore is not allowed for identifiers in the global namespace).

Comment: A leading underscore is fine for _lowercase but not for _Uppercase (in namespace and class scope)

Comment: @DieterLücking: No, sorry, your correction is wrong. However, leading underscore followed by uppercase is reserved for all names, not just in the global namespace. So that's a slightly different rule.

Answer (score 1):

I am not 100% sure what you are trying to do. However, since char* is a pointer you may be able to simply pass around the references.

```
char* operator=(char* s) { str = s; }
```

Just know that then if you modify value in your function it will modify the place you copied it from

If the char* needs to actually be a clone, so that it does not modify the original value. You first need to obtain the length of the char*.

This can be done with this function

```
unsigned Length(char* s)
{
   unsigned I = 0;
   while( *(s+I) != '\0')
      I++;

   return I;
}
```

The a new string can be created as follows

```
str = new char[LENGTH];
```

At that point you can copy the string over term by term

```
for(I = 0 ; I < LENGTH; I++)
{
   str[I] = s[I];
}
```

Finally to avoid memory leaks this needs to be deleted in the class destructor

```
~A()
{
    delete [] str;
}
```

Of course using std::string could save a lot of problems.